# add jQuery plug in my asp.net website

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, vb.net

I want to add a plug-in in my asp.net/vb website

This is the plug-in

http://archive.slidesjs.com/

I never worked with javaScript.

Comment: Have you tried searching? Have you even _read_ the page you're linking to?

Comment: yes for sure
they said add the plugin to the path then drag it
i did that but it's not working

Comment: Read the page sample. You need to include the plugin path as a script tag. What installation guide are you referring to?

Comment: sorry but what do you mean by installation guide? if you mean kind i want to use with caption one
i add it as a script tag to my code  already

Comment: If you show us how far you have got, we might be able to help you better. By "installation guide", I meant the web page that said "add the plugin to the path then drag it". Seeing the installation guide might help us better estimate your progress

Comment: sorry i missed the link, by the way, i have delete what i have done
could you please give me an installation guide 
i have tried to search i have found many many different answers but not about using the plug in

Comment: So, is your issue resolved now by having read the documentation?

Comment: The usual way to install javascript plugins is: 1) unpack them somewhere visible. If the plugin has a Content Distribution Network, this step may be skipped. This one doesn't seem to. 2) create a `<script...></script>` tag pointing to them, after the script tags pointing to the resources they require. In your case, after the jQuery tag. 3) Use the plugin as described. In case of jQuery plugins, most often you just need to do `$.pluginName(params)` or `$(selector).pluginName(params)`. Points 2 and 3 are well demonstrated on the script page.

Comment: thanks
the last thing should be in my html???
i mean $.pluginName(params) or $(selector).pluginName(params)

Comment: Not literally; that's how you use the plugin from your javascript code.

Comment: The `pluginName` is different in each case; you need to substitute that. The `params` can differ. Sometimes there are none needed. The `selector` targets the elements you want the plugin to act upon. Often, only one form (method of jQuery itself or method of jQuery instances) is valid. Please read a tutorial. This question is too broad, and I have to leave now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your Plugin Link into the [ ] i made. You can add more of this "script" lines

< script src="[Here the Link of your plugin]"> < /script >

(Delete spaces)